# How can I visually compare OSX fonts with my primary webfont choice to determine fallbacks without an OSX device?

Tags: website-design, fonts, workflow, resource-recommendations, osx

How can a freelance web designer who doesn't own a Mac visually identify and compare fonts similar to their primary webfont choice, that are present on most OSX devices?

I need to define a fallback font stack for a website for:

- when webfonts fail to load/render
- decrepit browsers on older Apple systems don't support webfonts
- The font that sometimes appears before the webfont renders in some browsers

  (I'd prefer for it to be as close to the webfont as possible to lessen the appearance of change when the webfont does render)

---

I've found a tool called [CSS Font Stack](http://www.cssfontstack.com/) which lists common Windows/Mac fonts and their availability, but it only renders the Windows fonts for me, and the default stacks aren't great, so it's almost as time-consuming as looking up a list and checking each individually, and I still don't have a way to see the Mac fonts rendered in paragraphs, headings, different font sizes etc.

There are also many exhaustive lists around that will take ages to peruse, find and compare fonts well. This is quite a simple part of a website design project, and shouldn't be given too much time, but it is a requirement of a well-rounded website design.

Is there a resource anywhere that I can use to quickly render Mac fonts reliably, or at least a decent list of screenshots of the available fonts on OSX sorted into type categories?

**What can I do to find similar fallback fonts available on OSX, when I don't own a Mac?**

Comment: A google search for "Fonts included in Mac OS" will answer this. Then subsequent looking at a font vendor would provide visual reference.

Comment: Recent versions of OS X come with all common Web fonts, so this would not seem to be a problem.

Comment: Web fonts are web fonts. They are customarily platform agnostic (otf, ttf, etc). and fallbacks are only if it fails to load. That would be solved by looking at the fonts included in the Mac OS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks any evidence of effort by the asker. This is widely available information.

Comment: User grudges? This is just a question that can easily be googled, is all.

Comment: Dom, there's no "grudge" come on. You *know* this is easily solved with a Google search.

Comment: @Scott If it's not a grudge it's Mac-tunnel-vision ;P It's really not easy on a Windows computer, and not something I should spend more than an hour on because it's so simple, but all options are potentially hours - days long if I want to do it well. It's not something I could reasonably bill a few hours for, yet that's what it will surely take, unless I just accept a lower quality result. The VM option is a genuinely useful long term method for me, and has basically solved it. I don't think I would've come to that conclusion myself.

Comment: Actually, I think the VM option is *way* more than what's needed. If I know I've got a serif type stack, all I need to know is are the serif fonts on an OS. Maybe it's just me but I can pick out Times, Palatino, Garamond, Georgia, etc. by their names. Perhaps you were just unclear.... do you mean you want to see what a page **renders** as without a Mac??? In that case it may be a duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37421/what-are-some-of-the-benefits-of-having-a-mac-vs-a-windows-pc-in-a-design-enviro/37422#37422

Comment: @Scott I'm hoping to be a little more specific/accurate with my serif choices as I'm not using typical serif fonts. My sans is not so distinguished. VM may appear to be an extreme solution, but it has additional benefits (such as proper OSX testing) and I can complete this task much faster on future projects with the same VM. I'm open to quicker workflows for this task but currently I've only got the VM as a viable option. I hope you can agree this is a design task.

Comment: But Dom, the answer is basically... find the names of the fonts... go look at them. Do that once and you have a reference to *all* future choices.  Perhaps I'm just not understanding why you feel this is more complicated than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, there are ways. Here are some options in order asc from shitty and easy, to less shitty and hard.

- Rely entirely on [this one article](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp) and make sure to always use `serif` or `sans-serif` as the final font in your list.
- Check out the OS font stack for OSX [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_OS_X). Google around for type specimens for those fonts, and trust that it looks ok in your usage.
- Do the same as above, but actually check to make sure it looks ok on the computer of a friend who owns a mac. What no [friends](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/friendmaker/id704606893?mt=8) with macs?
- Semi-legally install OSX into a virtual machine on your Windows PC. There are *cough easily accessible [instructions online](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Run-Mac-OS-X-Inside-Windows-Using-VirtualBo/). Then view your website on there.
- Buy and iPad, and view your website on iOS. iOS and OSX available fonts and rendering are remarkably similar.
- Buy a Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, lmao at the friends link, I need to action some of that advice on here if I want help. I wasn't aware there was an easy way to create a Mac VM so I think that's probably what I'll go for, as it allows other Mac testing aswell. I'm going to wait a few days to accept to see if anyone else chimes in with some good options, if not it's a guaranteed accept. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Dom while running OSX on non-Apple hardware is possible ("hackintosh") it's not necessarily pain-free to set up. If time is money for you, it'd probably be easier to buy a used Mac Mini or something for a couple of hundred bucks.

Comment: @DA01 I'm familiar with setting up VMs so in my case it's a good option, probably not for everyone. I appreciate the advice, and while yes, time is *potential* money, money is actual money :). I'd rather not have to purchase an additional device just to determine font stacks, testing directly on Macs is not a necessity for me, just an added benefit of using a VM.

Comment: @Dom there's more to it than just setting up a VM. Just be wary of that.

Comment: (FWIW, I tried the VM route a few years ago and it was a huge pain and I never did get it fully running in the end. If you have the time, by all means, give it a shot. It can be fun if you get it working. Just note that it's a fragile endeavor and any update can come along and break thing on you. I believe your current PC also has to be 'hackintosh friendly' so check that prior)

Comment: @DA01 I too thought it was notoriously hard to achieve for the past 5 years at least, I think it's a very recent breakthrough for pirates/tech-freedom-fighters. The setup looks easy, and whilst I haven't confirmed it yet, I think my hardware is compatible. :) (I'm going to purchase a license from the Apple store first of course;)

Comment: @Dom report back and let us know how it goes! As for purchasing an OSX license...I don't think you can. They don't actually sell OSX anymore.

Comment: @DA01 Oh yes, shows how much I know lol, I was reading the old tutorial linked to here which mentioned purchasing, further reading did say Mavericks was released for free, I just forgot very quickly. :)

Comment: VM with OSX, or getting an iPad are the 2 best options I think.