# Adobe Photoshop : Display text-selection in correct format

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, fonts, selections

I am working on a photoshop design for a font-design which will be inserted in html. Right now, when the text is selected, it looks differently in Photoshop and differently in browser(FF).

[image: Image in PS]

As you can see in the image above, when the font when selected in browser looks like in the first row, and in PS as in the 2nd row.

The problem is I would like to see in PS, when selection is made to look like in first row.

I am personally not a PS expert, my designer colleague is, I am posting a question on her behalf for language reasons. Below is what she wants in her words, in-case I missed something out. Thanks a lot. :-)

> We have build a Layout in Photoshop. Now I wanted to give the Layout
>   to the Programer to build it in html and I want to give him the space
>   from the textbox to the bottom of an objekt above. My problem is in
>   Photoshop the textbox ist not so high like the textbox in html in the
>   browser. The font is Segoe UI. The Browser ist Firefox. Can anyone
>   please help me how I can give him the exact space between the text and
>   the object above? I tried it in different font-sizes and the spaces
>   grows of course with the size but not in an reproduceable or linear
>   way. Please check out the picture.
>
> Thank u for answers.

Have a good day. :-)

*Edit*

Picture updated. 
When Photoshop is not the right program to handle text and the spaces to other objects in an exacly way how else can I give the exact space to an object above, so that it looks 100% the same in html and in photoshop?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7909/how-can-i-make-my-photoshop-text-appear-like-it-does-on-the-web

Comment: @Scott : I have updated the question after reading your answer as well as the image. Can you read the new edit in the main-post. Thanks a lot.. :-)

Comment: You will have to fiddle with the text element's `padding` manually.

Comment: Hi Borg, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: You're trying to match text selection between two different tools? Photoshop and FireFox? Does that even make any sense? They probably have majorly different levels of support for for certain font/text features and I don't think it will be possible to achieve "pixel-perfection" between two, very different, rendering systems.

Comment: @bemdesign : Any suggestions?